# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'Sifarisler'.'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

how can i fix this error.I couldn't understand why the error happened

Comment: by any chance could what you refer to as "Sifaris" actually be "Siparis"? the rest of the entity names are in Turkish, and "Sifaris" definitely looks like a typo if "Siparis". maybe that's it.

Comment: Can you please add your code as text? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: There is and Edit feature you can use to add information to your question

Comment: Images instead of formatted text for technical information like code is the fastest way I've seen here for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored. **No one** here wants to see screenshots of your code.

Comment: check whether the table 'Sifarisler' exists in the database, if not then create the table or create & apply ef migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you failed to do migrations correctly for this Sifaris model. Go to Package Manager Console from the menu Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console in Visual Studio->Write command **Add-migration Initial** and then **Update-database** and it will resolve your issue.